# Conditions when a non-convex set can be represented as the union of a finite number of convex sets

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, non-convex-optimization

Are there any theoretical results (including theorems, algorithms, etc) on representing a non-convex set as the union of a finite number of convex sets?

Comment: In what context? How many convex sets? Are you for example asking is there a result on the minimum number of convex sets needed to write every set as a union of at most that many convex sets? Maybe every connected set? I.e. what exactly is your question?

Comment: Good point. I'm thinking about two steps: (1) is the number of convex sets finite? Can we prove it? (2) If finite, what is the exact number (or a upper bound)?

Comment: Think about the integers in $\mathbb{R}$. Or worse, the Cantor set. You can only hope for finiteness if your set is connected. But then think of the circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. That also can't be the union of a finite number of convex sets.

Comment: Perhaps you want open and connected?

Comment: I think however, that a smooth concavity in the set will pose problems. E.g. an open annulus.

Comment: Take a look at [Mixed-Integer Programming for Control](http://acl.mit.edu/milp/MILP_for_Control.pdf) [PDF].

Answer (score 1):

I think the general case is hopeless: I don't expect a "typical" set, even an open, connected one, to be representable as the finite union of convex sets.

If you are OK with *approximating* your set, you can try to compute an approximating triangulation; NB that triangulation in high dimensions is itself a nontrivial problem. Algorithms exists for computing approximate convex decompositions in two and [three](http://kmamou.blogspot.com/2011/10/hacd-hierarchical-approximate-convex.html) dimensions, which try to minimize the number of convex pieces. I don't have much hope for a computationally tractable approach in high dimensions as even the 3D case is an active area of research in computational geometry.