# Is it possible to represent an open and connected set in $(\mathbb{R}^n,||\cdot||)$ as the finite union of convex sets?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

A similar question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2597921/conditions-when-a-non-convex-set-can-be-represented-as-the-union-of-a-finite-num), but there was no setting given.

Comment: It seems doubtful in general. For example, I doubt you could represent the exterior of the unit ball in that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take, for instance$$\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\bigl(\{n\}\times[0,\infty)\bigr).$$

Comment: Why is this connected?  Its a $xy$-plane separated by vertical lines $x = n$.

Comment: They're not lines. They're half-lines. It's the plane minus the vertical half-lines starting on points of the type $(n,0)$ and going up from there.

Comment: And the reason it can't be written as a finite union of convex sets would be, for example, that each point $(n+\frac{1}{2}, 1)$ would have to be in a different one of the convex sets?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yes, that's it.